# What is a difference between these two "slice copy" approaches in Go

Tags: arrays, go, slice

So, why are they (No.1 & No.2 below) different?

```golang
type T1 struct {
    local []string
}

func (t *T1) Assign(param ...string) {
    t.local = nil
    t.local = append(t.local, param...) // No.1 <<<
    t.local = param[:]                  // No.2 <<<
}
```

They **ARE** different, for sure: No.2 is quite "shallow".

When one change `t.local[i]`, she will garble the *original* string if No.2 was in use.

Comment: What do you mean they are different? In terms of end result they are the same... so you need to be more specific. What exactly are you asking about here?

Comment: The No.2 looks to be copying only references to the strings.
When one change `t.local[i]` she will garble the original string if No.2 was in use.
I ain't sure I formulate it good enough...

Comment: AFAIK strings are always passed/copied by reference in go. The string object holds a pointer to the underlying data.

Comment: @super: Nothing is passed by reference in Go. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/47296325/13860

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/slices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "No.1" approach appends to a `nil` slice which guarantees that a new backing array will be allocated if there are more than zero params provided.

Your "No.2" approach doesn't create a new slice, it just slices the param.

If `Assign()` is called by passing an existing slice, the 2nd approach will store that, and if its elements are modified, it will be reflected in the stored slice.

Let's modify your example a little to test it:

```
type T1 struct {
    local []string
}

func (t *T1) Assign1(param ...string) {
    t.local = nil
    t.local = append(t.local, param...) // No.1 <<<
}

func (t *T1) Assign2(param ...string) {
    t.local = nil
    t.local = param[:] // No.2 <<<
}
```

Testing it:

```
t1 := &T1{}

s := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
t1.Assign1(s...)
fmt.Println(t1.local)
s[0] = "x"
fmt.Println(t1.local)

s = []string{"a", "b", "c"}
t1.Assign2(s...)
fmt.Println(t1.local)
s[0] = "x"
fmt.Println(t1.local)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/poplRU7bJ9W)):

```
[a b c]
[a b c]
[a b c]
[x b c]
```

As you can see, when using `Assing1()`, the `local` slice is not affected by modifying the passed slice.

When using `Assing2()`, elements of the `local` slice reflect the changes made in the original.

Please read relevant blog posts:

[The Go Blog: Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro)

[The Go Blog: Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](https://blog.golang.org/slices)