# string vs integer as map key for memory utilization in golang?

Tags: multithreading, go, data-structures, concurrency, goroutine

I have a below `read` function which is called by multiple `go routines` to read `s3` files and it populates two [concurrent map](https://github.com/orcaman/concurrent-map) as shown below.

- During server startup, it calls `read` function below to populate two concurrent map.
- And also periodically every 30 seconds, it calls `read` function again to read new s3 files and populate two concurrent map again with some new data.

So basically at a given state of time during the whole lifecycle of this app, both my `concurrent map` have some data and also periodically being updated too.

```
func (r *clientRepository) read(file string, bucket string) error {
    var err error
    //... read s3 file

    for {
        rows, err := pr.ReadByNumber(r.cfg.RowsToRead)
        if err != nil {
            return errs.Wrap(err)
        }
        if len(rows) <= 0 {
            break
        }

        byteSlice, err := json.Marshal(rows)
        if err != nil {
            return errs.Wrap(err)
        }
        var productRows []ParquetData
        err = json.Unmarshal(byteSlice, &productRows)
        if err != nil {
            return errs.Wrap(err)
        }

        for i := range productRows {
            var flatProduct definitions.CustomerInfo
            err = r.ConvertData(spn, &productRows[i], &flatProduct)
            if err != nil {
                return errs.Wrap(err)
            }

            // populate first concurrent map here
            r.products.Set(strconv.FormatInt(flatProduct.ProductId, 10), &flatProduct)
            for _, catalogId := range flatProduct.Catalogs {
                strCatalogId := strconv.FormatInt(int64(catalogId), 10)
                // upsert second concurrent map here
                r.productCatalog.Upsert(strCatalogId, flatProduct.ProductId, func(exists bool, valueInMap interface{}, newValue interface{}) interface{} {
                    productID := newValue.(int64)
                    if valueInMap == nil {
                        return map[int64]struct{}{productID: {}}
                    }
                    oldIDs := valueInMap.(map[int64]struct{})
                    // value is irrelevant, no need to check if key exists
                    oldIDs[productID] = struct{}{}
                    return oldIDs
                })
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

In above code `flatProduct.ProductId` and `strCatalogId` are integer but I am converting them into string bcoz concurrent map works with string only. And then I have below three functions which is used by my main application threads to get data from the concurrent map populated above.

```
func (r *clientRepository) GetProductMap() *cmap.ConcurrentMap {
    return r.products
}

func (r *clientRepository) GetProductCatalogMap() *cmap.ConcurrentMap {
    return r.productCatalog
}

func (r *clientRepository) GetProductData(pid string) *definitions.CustomerInfo {
    pd, ok := r.products.Get(pid)
    if ok {
        return pd.(*definitions.CustomerInfo)
    }
    return nil
}
```

I have a use case where I need to populate map from multiple go routines and then read data from those maps from bunch of main application threads so it needs to be thread safe and it should be fast enough as well without much locking.

**Problem Statement**

I am dealing with lots of data like 30-40 GB worth of data from all these files which I am reading into memory. I am using concurrent map here which solves most of my concurrency issues but the key for the concurrent map is `string` and it doesn't have any implementation where key can be integer. In my case key is just a product id which can be int32 so is it worth it storing all those product id's as string in this concurrent map? I think string allocation takes more memory compare to storing all those keys as integer? At least it does in `c/c++` so I am assuming it should be same case here in `golang` too.

Is there anything I can to improve here w.r.t map usage so that I can reduce memory utilization plus I don't lose performance as well while reading data from these maps from main threads?

I am using `concurrent map` from this [repo](https://github.com/orcaman/concurrent-map) which doesn't have implementation for key as integer.

**Update**

I am trying to use cmap_int in my code to try it out.

```
type clientRepo struct {
    customers       *cmap.ConcurrentMap
    customersCatalog *cmap.ConcurrentMap
}

func NewClientRepository(logger log.Logger) (ClientRepository, error) {
  // ....
    customers := cmap.New[string]()
    customersCatalog := cmap.New[string]()

    r := &clientRepo{
        customers:       &customers,
        customersCatalog: &customersCatalog,
    }

  // ....
    return r, nil
}
```

But I am getting error as:

```
Cannot use '&products' (type *ConcurrentMap[V]) as the type *cmap.ConcurrentMap
```

What I need to change in my `clientRepo` struct so that it can work with new version of concurrent map which uses generics?

Comment: Your question is overly broad, the code not a minimal reproducable example, you are using uncommon 3rd party packages, you are asking about performance optimisations but did not show application profiles. Its unlikely someone will be able to give actionable advice unless you can provide more detail.

Comment: I don't think I can provide reproducable example bcoz there are so many s3 files I am reading which accounts for memory usage. So general question is using string as the map key adds more memory or using integer as the map keys make sense to reduce string allocation. If it is latter then concurrent map doesn't provide integer as the key

Comment: A int requires less storage than a string, but I do not know if this is _relevant_ to your problem because I do not _understand_ your problem.

Comment: Thank you. My problem is just reading s3 files and storing data into a concurrent map in my read method. That's all I am doing. Not sure what else I am missing in my question. I am trying to figure out if there is any way to use integer as the key and have it thread safe as well?

Comment: Use a simple `map[int]Value` with a `sync.RWMutex`.

Comment: @icza Do you think it is apt for my current problem? And then my maps needs to be updated by multiple go-routines and also it needs to be accessed from main application threads at higher throughput.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the implementation details of concurrent map in Go, but if it's using a string as a key I'm guessing that behind the scenes it's storing both the string and a hash of the string (which will be used for actual indexing operations).

That is going to be something of a memory hog, and there'll be nothing that can be done about that as concurrent map uses only strings for key.

If there were some sort of map that did use integers, it'd likely be using hashes of those integers anyway. A smooth hash distribution is a necessary feature for good and uniform lookup performance, in the event that key data itself is not uniformly distributed. It's almost like you need a very simple map implementation!

I'm wondering if a simple array would do, if your product ID's fit within 32bits (or can be munged to do so, or down to some other acceptable integer length). Yes, that way you'd have a large amount of memory allocated, possibly with large tracts unused. However, indexing is super-rapid, and the OS's virtual memory subsystem would ensure that areas of the array that you don't index aren't swapped in. **Caveat** - I'm thinking very much in terms of C and fixed-size objects here - less so Go - so this may be a bogus suggestion.

To persevere, so long as there's nothing about the array that implies initialisation-on-allocation (e.g. in C the array wouldn't get initialised by the compiler), allocation doesn't automatically mean it's all in memory, all at once, and only the most commonly used areas of the array will be in RAM courtesy of the OS's virtual memory subsystem.

EDIT

You could have a map of arrays, where each array covered a range of product Ids. This would be close to the same effect, trading off storage of hashes and strings against storage of null references. If product ids are clumped in some sort of structured way, this could work well.

Also, just a thought, and I'm showing a total lack of knowledge of Go here. Does Go store objects by reference? In which case wouldn't an array of objects actually be an array of references (so, fixed in size) and the actual objects allocated only as needed (ie a lot of the array is null references)? That doesn't sound good for my one big array suggestion...

Comment: [Does Go store objects by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296325/passing-by-reference-and-value-in-go-to-functions). I think you made very good points about the indexing and string key but unfortunately concurrent map implementation I am using doesn't work with integer as keys so that is why I don't have any other choice and yes indeed it is memory hog which is taking lot of memory in my application. I am scratching my head from quite sometime to figure out a better solution for this problem. I am not sure if we can build a concurrent map in go which works with integer as key

Comment: This is the [implementation](https://github.com/orcaman/concurrent-map/blob/master/concurrent_map.go) of go concurrent map just fyi.

Answer (score 2):

The [library](https://github.com/orcaman/concurrent-map/blob/master/concurrent_map.go) you use is relatively simple and you may just replace all `string` into `int32` (and modify the hashing function) and it will still work fine.

I ran a [tiny (and not that rigorous) benchmark](https://gist.github.com/gudzpoz/a442fef02a34437ac516cf274820bbb4) against the replaced version:

```
$ go test -bench=. -benchtime=10x -benchmem
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: maps
BenchmarkCMapAlloc-4             10  174272711 ns/op  49009948 B/op    33873 allocs/op
BenchmarkCMapAllocSS-4           10  369259624 ns/op 102535456 B/op  1082125 allocs/op
BenchmarkCMapUpdateAlloc-4       10  114794162 ns/op         0 B/op        0 allocs/op
BenchmarkCMapUpdateAllocSS-4     10  192165246 ns/op  16777216 B/op  1048576 allocs/op
BenchmarkCMap-4                  10 1193068438 ns/op      5065 B/op       41 allocs/op
BenchmarkCMapSS-4                10 2195078437 ns/op 536874022 B/op 33554471 allocs/op
```

Benchmarks with a `SS` suffix is the original string version. So using integers as keys takes less memory and runs faster, as anyone would expect. The string version allocates about 50 bytes more each insertion. (This is not the actual memory usage though.)

Basically, a string in go is just a struct:

```golang
type stringStruct struct {
    str unsafe.Pointer
    len int
}
```

So on a 64-bit machine, it takes at least `8 bytes (pointer) + 8 bytes (length) + len(underlying bytes)` bytes to store a string. Turning it into a int32 or int64 will definitely save memory. However, I assume that CustomerInfo and the catalog sets takes the most memory and I don't think there will be a great improvement.

(By the way, tuning the `SHARD_COUNT` in the library might also help a bit.)

Comment: sorry for delay in response as I was out. I updated my question where I was trying it out new version of concurrent map which uses generics but looks like I am missing something as I am getting an error. Any idea what I need to change in my struct definition so that it can work for me?

Comment: @AndyP You need to use `*cmap.ConcurrentMap[SOME_TYPE]` instead of `*cmap.ConcurrentMap` when using generics, where `SOME_TYPE` is your intended value type of the map. Also, I'm afraid you might be mixing up the original `cmap` and `cmap_int`. Please make sure you are not importing `github.com/orcaman/concurrent-map`.

Comment: yup I figured it out after going through the code base. It took me a while though. Also I am using `cmap_int` only in my actual code base. In the updated question I wrote it like that.

Comment: Looks like above shard logic will give `index out of range` error because `m[key%int64(SHARD_COUNT)]` is a slice lookup which is why we get an index-out-of-range when mod operation gives a negative result.